# Cropping strings in column in Python

Tags: python

I have a column of salaries that goes like this ( $12500 to $25000). I want to only keep the last 5 numbers of the whole column. How to do that?

Comment: Please add full sample data to make it clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: what did you try? Do you have normal list or `pandas.DataFrame`? if you have string then you can use string function for this - like `text[-6:-1]` gets last 6 chars and remove last `)`,  or `text.split('$')[-1].replace(')', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You have strings so use string's function for this

```
"($12500 to $25000)"[-6:-1]

"($12500 to $25000)".split('$')[-1].replace(')', '')

"($12500 to $25000)".split('$')[-1][:-1]
```

All of them gives `25000`

---

Now if you keep it in standard `list` (or nested lists) then you will have to use `for`-loop to run it on every string separatelly.

```
data = ["($12500 to $25000)", "($500 to $12000)"]

for item in data:
    print(item, '->', item.split('$')[-1][:-1])
```

Result

```
($12500 to $25000) -> 25000
($500 to $12000) -> 12000
```

---

If you keep in `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use `.apply()` or even directly `.str`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'salaries': ["($12500 to $25000)", "($500 to $12000)"]})
                  
def convert(text):
    return text.split('$')[-1][:-1]

df['result'] = df['salaries'].apply(convert)
print(df)
    
df['result'] = df['salaries'].apply(lambda text: text.split('$')[-1][:-1])
print(df)

df['result'] = df['salaries'].str.split('$').str[-1].str[:-1]
print(df)
```

Result

```
             salaries result
0  ($12500 to $25000)  25000
1    ($500 to $12000)  12000

             salaries result
0  ($12500 to $25000)  25000
1    ($500 to $12000)  12000

             salaries result
0  ($12500 to $25000)  25000
1    ($500 to $12000)  12000
```